# Ruby on Rails: What is the best way to make a registration form using a bootstrap modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, registration

I'm trying to make a registration form for a Ruby on Rails application using a bootstrap modal popup. I hardcoded the form myself from scratch (didn't use SimpleForm or Devise). I can't seem to make the data pass through when I click submit.

Here is the users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#before_action :confirm_logged_in   
respond_to :html, :js

def index
 @users = User.all.sorted
end

def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
 @user = User.new
end

def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_back }
  format.js
 end
 if @user.save
  flash[:success] = 'Welcome, #{@user.first_name}!'
 else
  render('new')
 end
end

def edit
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = 'You have been updated.'
    redirect_to(:action => 'show')
  else
    render('edit')
  end
end

def delete
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
 @user = User.find(params[:id]).destroy
 flash[:notice] = '#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name} has been deleted.'
 redirect_to ('home')
end

private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :confirm_password, :avatar)
end

end
```

Here is the view/layouts/application.html.erb where the modal is placed:

```
<button id="signupButton" data-toggle="modal", data-target="#registerModal">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_path, remote: true %>
        </button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">

 <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- REGISTER FORM -->

        <%= render 'users/register' %>

                <!-- END REGISTER FORM -->

    </div>

   </div>

</div>

</nav>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

And finally here is the form partial (_register.html.erb):

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <%= form_for :user, remote: true do |f| %>

 <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <%= f.label :first_name, class: "sr-only" %>
    <%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <%= f.label :last_name, class: "sr-only" %>                  
    <%= f.text_field(:last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last Name") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <%= f.label :email, class: "sr-only" %>
    <%= f.text_field(:email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <%= f.label :password, class: "sr-only" %>
    <%= f.password_field(:password, type: "password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <%= f.label :password, class: "sr-only" %>
    <%= f.password_field(:password, type: "password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Confirm Password") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>  

<div class="modal-footer">

  <%= link_to 'Close', "#", class: "btn btn-default", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
  <%= f.submit 'Register', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    </div>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

 get '/users', to: 'users#index'

 root 'access#index', as: '/'

 get '/home', to: 'home#home'

 #match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

 resources :users

 resources :sessions

end
```

Here is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password




before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

validates :first_name, :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 25 }
validates :last_name, :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\Z/i
validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false}, 
                    :length => { :maximum => 100 },
                    :format => { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    :confirmation => true
validates :password, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :within => 6..20 }
validates_confirmation_of :password
#mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
#validate :picture_size
validates :avatar, :attachment_presence => true
validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :avatar
validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes

scope :sorted, lambda { order("last_name ASC, first_name ASC") }

def name
 "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end

private

   def picture_size
    if picture.size > 5.megabytes
    errors.add(:picture, " must be less than 5MB")
   end
end

end
```

Comment: Please update your post with the `params log` generated when you click `submit`.

Comment: Remove `remote: true` from the form tag - it will use the rails-ujs driver to send the form with ajax.

Comment: @max, Removing 'remote: true' worked as far as sending the data through but now I'm getting an error saying: No route matches [POST] "/home". Do you think I need to install the "js-routes" gem or something that will let me post when not on a "/users" page?

Comment: No, you most likely just need to add the correct route. Please add your routes.rb to the question. You also need to create a `@user = User.new` model instance which the form binds to. But if I was you I would actually load the form with ajax from `/users/new` and then throw in into the modal. Its alot cleaner than setting up your `ApplicationController` and `layout.html.erb` to handle rendering a user registration form.

Comment: @max, okay I've updated my original post to include my routes rile and user model file. I will look into using a different approach.

Comment: You do have a route for the form to post to - but I'm guessing that your form is still trying to post to '/' since you don't have a `@user` variable.

Comment: @max - I wonder if I need to set up a 'new.js.erb' or a partial like '_new.js.erb' file. I'm looking at this little tutorial right now - [link](https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails). If I have "@user" in the form instead of ":user" I get an error.

Comment: See my answer. Have a look at the `UsersController` in the linked github repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would load a form via ajax and inject it into a bootstrap **modal**. Please note that this is based on a [scaffolded rails app](https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/31105996) - you will need to adapt it to your own app.

[image: Screenshot]

### 1. Setup page specific javascript

Change the body tag in your `views/application/layout.html.erb`

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller_name %>" data-action="<%= action_name %>">
```

We then set up a listener in `assets/javascripts/application.js` which tells us which page has been loaded.

```
// This lets us bind "page specific javascript" by listening for the controller:action:loaded event.
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
    var data = $('body').data();
    var key = data['controller'] + ':' + data['action'] + ':loaded';
    console.log('Triggering', key);
    $(this).trigger(key);
});
```

This lets us just display the modal on the home page. Feel free to skip this step if your modal is not a "splash".

In my example I have `pages#home` as the root path.

### 2. Create a modal template

Create a generic modal template in `views/layouts/_modal.html.erb`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-template" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Generic Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include the partial in your `views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

```
    <!-- ... -->
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/modal' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

### 3. Create the registration form.

First create a users form partial `views/users/_form.html.erb`.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="form-errors">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <%= f.label :first_name, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <%= f.label :last_name, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.text_field(:last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last Name") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <%= f.label :email, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.text_field(:email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <%= f.label :password, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.password_field(:password, type: "password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <%= f.label :confirm_password, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= f.password_field(:confirm_password, type: "password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Confirm Password") %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then add the form to your `views/users/new.html.erb`.

```
<h1>New User</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

### 4. Load the form with Ajax.

This looks pretty complicated but it's not really. We make a copy of the modal template we added to the page and inject components from the form which we load with ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Only fire this on the home page.
    // Replace this with a regular click handler if you do not want a "splash"
    $(document).on('pages:home:loaded', function(){
        // Load the page content from "/users/new"
        var promise = $.get("/users/new");
        // When the ajax request has finished
        promise.success(function(data){
            var $frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), // Good for performance
                $modal = $($('#modal-template')[0].outerHTML, $frag),
                $form = $($(data).find('#new_user')[0].outerHTML),
                $btn = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');
            // Wrap the modal content in the form.
            // Give the modal a unique ID.
            $modal.attr('id', 'register-modal');
            // Add the inputs from the form inside the body
            $modal.find('.modal-body').append($form);
            // Customize the title
            $modal.find('.modal-title').text('Sign Up!');
            // Add the submit button next to the close button
            $btn.addClass('btn btn-primary');
            // since the button is not actually in the form we add an event handler to submit the form.
            $btn.click(function(){
                $modal.find('form').submit();
            });
            $modal.find('.modal-footer').append($btn);
            // Attach the modal to document
            $('body').append($modal);
            // Open the modal
            $modal.modal({});
        });
        promise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error('Failed to fetch user registration form', textStatus, jqXHR, errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you this is more of what I'm looking for! For some reason the modal body is just a search box. I wonder if the jQuery is just picking up the `role="form"` from the search box that is in the navbar.

Comment: Yeah, that most likely the case - use `$form = $($(data).find('#new_user')[0].outerHTML) ` or whatever the id of your form is.

Comment: The selector I used was really lax, it just took the first form from the page.